# Вопрос по ip-адресам в пакетах от ping'а

Tags: сеть, ip, ping

В Wireshark'е захватил два ping пакета - запрос и ответ.
IP-адрес отправителя : 192.168.1.3
IP-адрес получателя  : 192.168.1.1
И нужно сделать вывод исходя из IP-шников.

Я думаю, что эти два запроса, это просто "пинговка" двух компьютеров в одной локальной сети (у меня два ПК в локалке, там похожие результаты).

Но меня смущает значение предпоследнего байта IP-шников — 1.

Мой вопрос : прав ли я в том, что это "пинговка" двух компов из одной локальной сети?

Comment: Да. 192.168.*.* — это всегда локальная сеть.

Comment: А как интерпретировать последние два байта 1.3 и 1.1.
У меня дома локалка такая : два ПК подключены к роутеру, и у ПК последние два байта в IP 0.103 и 0.101.

Comment: Интерпретировать как адреса устройств в подсети 192.168.0.0/16. Ну, или как адреса в подсети 192.168.1.0/24. Например, 192.168.1.1 — заводская настройка адреса моего домашнего роутера. Или что Вы понимаете под словом "интерпретировать"?

Comment: Я похоже понял. Спасибо.

Comment: http://citforum.ru/nets/tcpip/index.shtml